# Is it safe to place thermistor on 18650 battery tab?

Tags: batteries, thermal, thermistor

I'm making a BMS for a 3S1P Battery Pack, with the intention of using two thermistors to measure the battery temperature and let the circuit know when a battery is too hot or too cold. The battery pack is going to go into a narrow 3D printed tube, so the cells need to be stacked on top of one another. Because of that, I was thinking of placing the thermistors right on the exposed tab of the 18650 cell, and wanted to know if this would be a good idea in terms of thermal measurements, and of course, safety. Below is a crude drawing to show where I'm trying to place the thermistor, for a better reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"...two thermistors to **measure** the battery temperature and let the circuit know when a battery is too hot or too cold"_ - Your thermistors are for measuring temperature. So why are you showing them as cell inter-connects?

Comment: If the termistor is put right on the exposed tab, how would the tab make contact to the other battery?

Comment: The intent would be to spot weld the three batteries, and place a thermistor on two of the spot weld tabs.

Comment: You will have to electrically isolate them but they should work good.

Comment: Of all the battery packs I've opened - And I've opened MANY - The thermistor invariably is placed such that its touching the middle of the cell - Not the end cap.

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer, but if you're 3d printing the tube why not add a notch in the profile to accommodate the thermistors on the side of the battery? You need some way to get the balance wires out anyway.

Comment: @Drew Well basically, the reason I'm asking this question is because I'm trying to avoid using three thermistors, if I don't have too. I'm using the BQ77915, which only has one thermistor input pin. I have a external circuit that allows me to use two thermistors with the one input pin, and I would rather not use 3 since it would make the circuit more complex.